# Xcode autocomplete, possible values for placeholders?

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, keyboard-shortcuts

In Xcode, let's say I create an object, and then want to call some setters:

```
CLLocationManager* locMan;
locMan = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

[locMan setDesiredAccuracy:<#(CLLocationAccuracy)#>]; // placeholder text
```

When I'm typing the 3rd line, I can easily autocomplete the "setDesiredAccuracy" part, and Xcode fills in `<#(CLLocationAccuracy)#>` for the placeholder parameter value.

Is there a mechanism within autocomplete to get a list of possible values `(kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation, kCLLocationAccuracyBest, kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters, etc)`, at least for cases like this one? Obviously in many instances a list of possible values would be meaningless...

The only way I really know of doing something like this, when I either don't know at all or forget the name of a constant, is double clicking the placeholder to make it convert to actual text and then doing something like Option+Double Click or Control+Option+Shift+? to search the documentation for CLLocationAccuracy.

Answer (score 0):

In nearly every case, you can start typing either the typedef name of the enum or the typedef name preceded by "k" (as in this instance).

So, here you're given "CLLocationAccuracy"; typing "kcllocationacc" and asking for autocompletion gives you the possible choices. (You'll notice I don't bother with capitalization, as autocompletion is going to fix that for me.)

Cases like this where you have to supply the "k" are mercifully few. Usually the enum typedef name *is* the start of the possible choices. For example, an `autoresizingMask` is a `UIViewAutoresizing` (and you're told this as `autoresizingMask` is autocompleted) and all the possible choices start with "UIViewAutoresizing". So you just type "uiviewauto" and ask for autocompletion and there you are.

Also there are techniques for learning the names outside of autocomplete that you didn't mention; for example, select within the name of the enum and press command-option-2 to read the Quick Help.